# Is it faster to apply multiple indexes to a table one after the other or with multiple individual queries

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

This is not about multiple column indexes (composite) vs single column indexes. This is about performance more so than function.

I have a scenario where I need to apply multiple indexes to the same table.  Right now I have it check if they exist and then apply them one after the other.

My question is, from a start to end total time it takes more than a few hours to apply them all.  I want to reduce that total time as much as possible (reduce the time window to apply them)

serial one after the other

`index1 => index2 = index3 =>...indexN`

All being applied at same time to a table

```
index1 
index2 
index3 
...
indexN
```

The index count is 10+ on some tables, there are multiple tables, and this will be applied to multiple databases (a few hundred) I do not have any control over the data store or the SQL Server here for SAN magic type things.  I have 16 processors and an Enterprise server but the total of all tables in all databases is non-trivial. Think in terms of multiple GB row table counts and multiple TB storage size for all of them in nearly 3000 tables.  These are all clustered indexes and most are composite

Comment: update your sql server version and move to column store index feature

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Not an option, that is a task for another day with a good deal of work behind that

Comment: Do you want to rebuild those index every night or it is a once-off action?

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski This is a one-off but it is pretty large set of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a simple method to accomplish this does not appear to exist, if was found with testing against a fairly large table that application of 10 new indexes with separate queries and configuration **concurrently processing** (all started at nearly the same time, separately) **was indeed faster than a single script** where the indexing was applied in a serial fashion by a significant margin.  This also appeared to have no negative impact that could be detected provided the SQL Server has enough resources to handle the impact.

Just to update the scope and scale here without getting too specific:

- Tested against multiple tables with scale from trivial (3.6M rows) to larger
- Tested against sets with 30+ indexes (200M-500M rows)
- Tested against tables with 1.6B to 1.9B rows
- Index counts varied from 3-30+ depending on the table
- tempdb size was 1TB
- total scope from 0 rows to nearly 2B rows in 2800+ tables
- Server was basically loaded to the maximum point it could handle and kept there using automation

Actual result examples were consistent with 9 to 14 hour completion times reduced to less than 43 minutes, all the indexes being applied at the same time on a single table and multiple tables indexing in one database as well as in over 200 separate databases.  A multiple TB level of data size.

I submitted the index additions using Powershell with several hundred running at once on different tables including over 30 on several tables.